# Oneliner in R to replace upper triangle of a matrix with its lower triangle?

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal

How to copy the lower triangle of a matrix to the upper triangle of that same matrix?

```
mat <- t(lower.tri(mat) * mat) + lower.tri(mat) * mat
```

...does not keep the diagonal (I know it shouldn't.).

I can save the diagonal to a separate variable before the operation and bring it back after the operation. But this feels so clumsy:

```
diag_mat <- diag(mat)
mat <- t(lower.tri(mat) * mat) + lower.tri(mat) * mat
diag(mat) <- diag_mat
```

Any ideas how to do this as a oneliner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```r
mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9

mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- t(mat)[upper.tri(mat)]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    2    5    6
# [3,]    3    6    9
```

Comment: This seems only work with 3x3 matrices?
mat <- matrix(1:81, nrow = 9);
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- mat[lower.tri(mat)];
Looking weird...

Comment: True. See edit. Using `t` solves the problem